# A special group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose you have a table of two columns, some dates in the first column and values associated to those columns in the second. Suppose that some values repeat themselves a lot. So for example,

```
2009-03-04 1.0
2009-03-05 0.0
2009-03-06 1.2
2009-03-09 0.0
2009-03-10 0.0
2009-03-11 3.0
2009-03-12 0.0
2009-03-13 0.0
```

Is there a special way of using group by to obtain something of the following format:

```
2009-03-05 0.0
2009-03-09 0.0
2009-03-12 0.0
```

So basically you select the min value for the date in those "groups" where you have 0.0 in this case?

Comment: What version of SQL server are u using?

Comment: so you only want the min value in the table and list those dates ?

Comment: You want consecutive groups?

Comment: Yes. Consecutive groups' min date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
declare @t table(d date, i decimal(5,2))
insert @t values
('2009-03-04', 1.0),
('2009-03-05', 0.0),
('2009-03-06', 1.2),
('2009-03-09', 0.0),
('2009-03-10', 0.0),
('2009-03-11', 3.0),
('2009-03-12', 0.0),
('2009-03-13', 0.0)

;with x as (
    select *, sum(i) over(order by d) g
    from @t
),
y as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by g order by d) rn
    from x 
    where i = 0
)
select d, i
from y
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a variation on the greatest-n-by-group problem (actually the smallest n per group). You can find more info on it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i entirely understand your question but to get the result in your first statement

```
select * from table 
where value in (select min(eValue) from table)
```